# QT 5.3.2 linux libmysqlclient

Tags: mysql, linux, qt, mysql-connector

I've installed Qt 5.3.2 64bit in my kali linux (based on debian), And I'm getting some trouble connecting to a MySQL database.

First of all, for some reason the prebuilt qsqlmysql qt driver depends on libmysqlclient16 (ldd says libmysqlclient_r.so.16 not found) instead of the libmysqlclient18 (libmysqlclient.so.18) that comes by default with this distro! Making a symbolic link and naming it libmysqlclient_r.so.16 doesn't work.
so, I looked for a libmysqlclient16 for debian (squeeze iirc) and installed it!

```
ruido@Developer2:~$ ldd /opt/Qt5.3.2/5.3/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so 
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff4a9ce000)
libmysqlclient_r.so.16 => /usr/lib/libmysqlclient_r.so.16 (0x00007ffb99a3d000)
libQt5Sql.so.5 => /opt/Qt5.3.2/5.3/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/../../lib/libQt5Sql.so.5 (0x00007ffb997fc000)
(...)
```

It works, but has a big issue... It's probably outdated and I need to use it to connect to >5.6 mysql servers, to be able to use milliseconds on datetimes (since mysql 5.6.4).
libmysqlclient doesn't seem to support that and every timestamp I fetch from the DB comes with milliseconds filled with zeros.

So the question is:
Is there a way to make qsqlmysql look for libmysqlclient18 instead?
(Because I tryed it on a regular debian wheezy, and it looks fot libmysqlclient18 there)

Comment: Just rebuild the mysql plugin for your current plattform. Should be fine by going to ``$QTDIR/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql/`` run: ``qmake "LIBS+=-L/usr/lib/ -lmysql" "INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/include/" mysql.pro && make``. This should build the mysql-plugin for Qt using the newest mysql-library found on your system. You may have to change the LIBS/INCLUDEPATH corresponding to your installed system.

Comment: I was trying to avoid that (cause I'm hugely lazy) but well... after updating everything mysql related as much as I could and after figuring out why it was not finding things like -lmysqlclient_r while building the new plugin, it worked just fine ;)
Thanks!

@SebastianLange create a formal answer if you want ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just rebuild the mysql plugin for your current plattform. Should be fine by going to `$QTDIR/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql/` run: `qmake "LIBS+=-L/usr/lib/ -lmysql" "INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/include/" mysql.pro && make`. This should build the mysql-plugin for Qt using the newest mysql-library found on your system. You may have to change the LIBS/INCLUDEPATH corresponding to your installed system.
                    – Sebastian Lange

I was trying to avoid that (cause I'm hugely lazy) but well... after updating everything mysql related as much as I could and after figuring out why it was not finding things like -lmysqlclient_r while building the new plugin, it worked just fine ;) …
                    – RuiDo